# A word or words to describe the relationship between humanity and the natural world

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, vocabulary

It's a bit of a hard one to describe but i'll try my best, and give a little context too:

So my project is about the way that humans 'use' nature for their own gains. It's more about the feeling that we shape nature around us rather than working with it - even though we rely so heavily on it.

To describe it simply:
Parasitic Interdependence

I feel like this is a bit too formal for me and might come off a bit pretentious but then at the same time I realize what i'm looking for probably won't be in the common tongue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: “(Over)exploitation of nature” comes to mind - but I'm not sure if this what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe something more along the lines of "anti-eutierria", but I still don't think that it really suits what i'm going for

Comment: . . . . dominion.

Comment: @Chris “anti-eutierria”? Less formal and pretentious? Lol!

Answer (score 1):

Myopic Manipulation. 
Human centric ecosystem.
Planet wide tool / Earth as a tool.
Earth: Humanity's Shell.
Primate Prime Directive.
Man Conforming Nature.

Answer (score 0):

**Parasitic** by itself has a lot going for it. From M-W:

> [**parasitic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasitic): exploiting the hospitality of others : depending on another or others for existence or support without making a useful or adequate return

Like any good **parasite**, we don't go so far as to wipe out our host -- planet Earth -- at least we haven't done so quite yet.

The *interdependent* part in your example target is harder to fathom: it's not at all clear how nature depends on us. Seems like pretty much of a one-way street.

Answer (score 0):

Predatory / predaceous / rapacious

[Rapacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rapacious): excessively grasping or covetous
[Predacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predaceous): tending to devour or despoil
[Predatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predatory):  inclined or intended to injure or exploit others for personal gain or profit

Comment: I edited my answer to include M-W’s definitions of the words I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is what is meant by "nature". Does it mean "things that are alive" or "our entire environment" or something in between?

Every living thing is dependent upon something for its existence - we cannot all be "parasites".

Parasitic interdependence is properly termed "symbiosis." Our relationship with nature is supposed to be **symbiotic**. We are not parasitic *per se*.  We simply happen to be the current alpha predator. If we do not make a useful or adequate return, our population is reduced such that our demands are naturally reduced, and then intelligence prompts us to amend our behaviour.

I suggest adapting "**unbalanced symbiosis**."